# binary operator overloading; implicit type conversion

Tags: c++

```
class my_bool {
  private:
    bool value;
  public:
    my_bool(bool value) : value(value) {}
    operator bool();

    friend my_bool operator==(const my_bool & instance_1, const my_bool & instance_2);
};

void main(){
  my_bool a = true;
  bool b = false;

  if(a == b){
    // do something
  }
}
```

The compiler says that comparison operator is ambiguous. Compiler cannot decide whether `a` should be converted to `bool` or `b` should be converted to `my_bool`. Is there a way I can solve this problem without writing down 3 overloads (`my_bool`, `my_bool`), (`bool`, `my_bool`), (`my_bool`, `bool`) of the same comparison operator?

Comment: Not an answer as based on how I interpret you're going to use your class, it would be a hindrance, but you _could_ mark your constructor as `explicit` (I don't think this is a good idea based on your class name, as it would seem you would want implicit conversions).

Comment: I do not mind making `my_bool` to `bool` conversion explicit, that is `explicit operator bool();`. I would expect this ambiguity to be solved that way, but it does not solve anything (and I'm not sure why not)

Comment: Hmm, I tried the same and the ambiguity _does_ goes away.

Comment: Ah, my bad! The actual operator I am trying out is `friend my_bool operator&&(const my_bool&, const my_bool&);`. That one causes ambiguities to me surely

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `const` qualifer on the second second parameter to get rid of the ambiguity:

```
friend my_bool operator==(const my_bool & instance_1, my_bool & instance_2);
```

http://ideone.com/30VfO1

Or use explicit

```
 explicit operator bool();
```

Or use a different `==` overload that make more sense like this:

```
class my_bool
{
private:
    bool value;
public:
    my_bool(bool value) : value(value) {}
    operator bool() { return value; }

    bool operator == (bool val)
    {
        return this->value == val;
    }
};
```

http://ideone.com/fBaiKp

Comment: As of my understanding`operator==` should be declared as a friend function, because otherwise this case `bool == my_bool` becomes problematic. `explicit` thing solves the ambiguity problem for `operator==`, but not for `operator&&`. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

You could *explicitly* convert `a` to a `bool`

```
  if(((bool) a) == b){ // yes, this is a cast.
      // do something
  }
```