# binary operator overloading, implicit type conversion

Tags: c++

```
class my_bool {
  private:
    bool value;
  public:
    my_bool(bool value) : value(value) {}
    explicit operator bool() { return value };

    friend my_bool operator==(const my_bool & instance_1, const my_bool & instance_2);
    friend my_bool operator&&(const my_bool & instance_1, const my_bool & instance_2);

};

void main(){
  my_bool a = true;
  bool b = false;

  if(a == b){
    // do something
  }

  if(a && b){
    // do something 
  }
}
```

I have just created a similar topic regarding my problem over here [binary operator overloading; implicit type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391795/binary-operator-overloading-implicit-type-conversion) . It can be deleted I guess because it is not explicit enough about the problem I am encountering.

Why is that `operator==` works fine and `operator&&` causes ambiguities? How do I solve this problem? I can surely write down two more overloads of `operator&&` (`bool`, `my_bool`), (`my_bool`, `bool`). That is a messy solution though

Comment: `void main()` *No*. `int main()`.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because `&&` is a context where the argument is *contextually converted to bool*, and that allows convertors marked `explicit`. The other such contexts are: operator `!`, `||`, first operand of `?`, `if`, `do`, `while`, `static_assert`, `noexcept`

Comment: Actually `explicit` keyword shows, that no implicit conversion `my_bool` to `bool` is allowed. Such conversion can only be done explicitly `(bool)my_bool_instance`. That means compiler should not even consider `my_bool` to `bool` implicit conversion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The builtin `operator&&` is a context in which expressions are *contextually converted* to `bool`. Other such contexts include for example the condition of `if`, `for`, `while` and the conditional operator `?`.

Quoting [N4296, §4/4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (the latest publicly available draft before C++14):

> Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted to a Boolean value. An expression `e`
>   appearing in such a context is said to be contextually converted to `bool` and is well-formed if and only if the
>   declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5).

Basically, this means that there is an "impicit explicit conversion to `bool`" in these contexts. Or, to illustrate this further, you can think of the following two lines being one and the same:

```
a && b
static_cast<bool>(a) && static_cast<bool>(b)
```

Therefore, the compiler must consider the `explicit operator bool()` when doing overload resolution for `operator&&`, but has to ignore it when doing overload resolution for `operator==` (since that operator does not force a "`bool` context" .. you can also compare numbers, strings, ...).

---

The solution in your case is IMO to get rid of the `operator&&(const my_bool&, const my_bool&)` all together. After all, it does not produce a more meaningful behavior than what would be possible by relying on the builtin `operator&&(bool, bool)`. <s>Establishing a second "boolean context" just isn't something the language was designed for</s> (see below).

If you want to keep this operator, say for some side effects, then I see these choices:

- Be explicit at the call site. That is:

  ```
  if (static_cast<my_bool>(a) && static_cast<my_bool>(b)) { /* ... */ }
  ```
- Be explicit at the definition site: Provide additional definitions for `operator&&(my_bool const &, bool)`, `operator&&(bool, my_bool const &)`. These then should rule out both `operator&&(my_bool const &, my_bool const &)` as well as `operator&&(bool, bool)` because the later are less specific. Adding these definitions to your class [should mitigate the issue](http://ideone.com/wEzUT6):

  ```
  friend my_bool operator&&(const my_bool & lhs, bool rhs) {
      // Delegate to operator&&(const my_bool &, const my_bool &)
      return lhs && my_bool(rhs);
  }
  friend my_bool operator&&(bool lhs, const my_bool & rhs) {
      // Delegate to operator&&(const my_bool &, const my_bool &)
      return my_bool(lhs) && rhs;
  }
  ```

---

Turns out one can "establish a boolean context", using CRTP:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct bool_context {
    friend T operator&&(T const & lhs, bool rhs) {
        return lhs && T(rhs);
    }
    friend T operator&&(bool lhs, T const & rhs) {
        return T(lhs) && rhs;
    }
    friend T operator||(T const & lhs, bool rhs) {
        return lhs || T(rhs);
    }
    friend T operator||(bool lhs, T const & rhs) {
        return T(lhs) || rhs;
    }
};

struct my_bool : bool_context<my_bool> {
    bool value;
    my_bool(bool v) : value(v) {}
    explicit operator bool() { return value; };
    friend my_bool operator&&(my_bool const & lhs, my_bool const & rhs) {
        cout << "my_bool::operator&&" << endl;
        return lhs.value && rhs.value;
    }
    friend my_bool operator||(my_bool const & lhs, my_bool const & rhs) {
        cout << "my_bool::operator||" << endl;
        return lhs.value || rhs.value;
    }
};


int main(int, char**) {
    my_bool a = true;
    bool b = false;
    cout << "a && b => "; a && b; // my_bool::operator&&
    cout << "b && a => "; b && a; // my_bool::operator&&
    cout << "a && a => "; a && a; // my_bool::operator&&
    cout << "b && b => "; b && b; cout << endl;
    cout << "a || b => "; a || b; // my_bool::operator||
    cout << "b || a => "; b || a; // my_bool::operator||
    cout << "a || a => "; a || a; // my_bool::operator||
    cout << "b || b => "; b || b; cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

([Ideone](http://ideone.com/V2dVza))

Comment: Have you got an answer for the second part of OP question (i.e. how to fix the code)

Comment: @MooingDuck No: Because of the context of `operator&&`, the explicit conversion is allowed to be applied (implicitly), thus making `operator&&(bool, bool)` a viable overload.

Comment: The result of that example code is something I can't understand... `operator&&(my_bool, my_bool)` was called and I would have expected `operator&&(bool, my_bool)`

Comment: I defined `operator&&(my_bool, bool)` as well as `operator&&(bool, my_bool)` to *call* `operator&&(my_bool, my_bool)` (leaving out `const &` for readability here). So in fact both were called, the one just delegates to the other so that you can have your intended behavior in just one function.

Comment: That is most likely the answer to this problem

Comment: @M.M I think I found a generic way to fix this, though the question remains whether it's useful or sound.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought on this is that the arguments to the compiler's built-in `operator&&` are `(bool, bool)`, so my_bool's explicit bool operator can be invoked - since you are in effect, requesting an explicit conversion.

However, I can't find any reference in the standard as to whether a variable appearing on the right hand side of && should invoke an explicit conversion to bool.

Here's the complete error output from apple clang (once the source code above is fixed):

```
./nod.cpp:45:10: error: use of overloaded operator '&&' is ambiguous (with operand types 'my_bool' and 'bool')
    if(a && b){
       ~ ^  ~
./nod.cpp:33:20: note: candidate function
    friend my_bool operator&&(const my_bool & instance_1, const my_bool & instance_2);
                   ^
./nod.cpp:45:10: note: built-in candidate operator&&(_Bool, _Bool)
    if(a && b){
         ^
1 error generated.
```

> So how do I fix it?

Remove the user-defined && operator.

```
class my_bool {
private:
    bool value;
public:
    my_bool(bool value) : value(value) {}
    explicit operator bool() { return value; }

    friend my_bool operator==(const my_bool & instance_1, const my_bool & instance_2);
//    friend my_bool operator&&(const my_bool & instance_1, const my_bool & instance_2);

};

int main(){
    my_bool a = true;
    bool b = false;

    if(a == b){
        // do something
    }

    if(a && b){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: See [expr.log.and]/1 for that reference

Comment: `a && b` should only return a result of `bool` type when both `a` and `b` are of `bool` type. Otherwise it should give a result of `my_bool` type. It's very important

Comment: @user3600124 ah, in that case you're stuck with having to provide explicit overloads as per the end of Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow works in the same manner for both == and &&. 
The class equality is triggered only when are of the same type.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class my_bool {
private:
  bool v{false};
  public:
    my_bool() : v(v) {};
    operator bool (){return v;}

    friend bool operator==(const my_bool a, my_bool b){
            printf("operator==\n");return a.v==b;
        }
        friend bool operator&&(const my_bool a, my_bool b){
            printf("operator&&\n");return a.v&&b;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ printf("Starting\n");
  bool a=true,b=true;
  my_bool A{},B{},R{};

  a==b;a&&b;
  a==A;a&&A;
  A==b;A&&b;
  A==B;A&&B;
}
```

Comment: It fixes ambiguity and it also does not allow implicit conversions `bool` to `my_bool` anymore such as `my_bool a = false`