# Preventing implicit conversion operator only for binary operators

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++17, implicit-conversion

I'm having an issue that I've boiled down to the following, where an `==` operator usage compiles even though it's supposed to fail (C++17, tested on GCC 5.x, 8.x, and 9.x):

```
template <int N> struct thing {
  operator const char * () const { return nullptr; }
  bool operator == (const thing<N> &) const { return false; }
};

int main () {
  thing<0> a;
  thing<1> b;
  a == b; // i don't want this to compile, but it does
}
```

The reason it is compiling is because the compiler is choosing to do this:

```
(const char *)a == (const char *)b;
```

Instead of this:

```
// bool thing<0>::operator == (const thing<0> &) const
a.operator == (b);
```

Because the latter isn't a match, since `b` is a `thing<1>` not a `thing<0>`. (Incidentally, it also produces `unused-comparison` warnings when the primitive comparison operator is used; not interesting, but that's why those warnings appear.)

I've verified this (actually it's how I discovered the cause) on [C++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/), which outputs:

```
template <int N> struct thing {
  operator const char * () const { return nullptr; }
  bool operator == (const thing<N> &) const { return false; }
};

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:7 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
struct thing<0>
{
  using retType_2_7 = const char *;
  inline operator retType_2_7 () const
  {
    return nullptr;
  }
  
  inline bool operator==(const thing<0> &) const;
  
  // inline constexpr thing() noexcept = default;
};

#endif


/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:8 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
struct thing<1>
{
  using retType_2_7 = const char *;
  inline operator retType_2_7 () const
  {
    return nullptr;
  }
  
  inline bool operator==(const thing<1> &) const;
  
  // inline constexpr thing() noexcept = default;
};

#endif


int main()
{
  thing<0> a = thing<0>();
  thing<1> b = thing<1>();
  static_cast<const char *>(a.operator const char *()) == static_cast<const char *>(b.operator const char *());
}
```

Showing the conversion operator usage in that last line of `main`.

My question is: Of course, the whole thing behaves properly if I make the conversion operator explicit, but **I'd really like to keep the implicit conversion operator *and* have the compiler enforce correct usage of `operator ==` (where "correct" = failing to compile if the parameter type is different). Is this possible?**

Note that it is *not* important to me to have `thing<N> == const char *` work. That is, I don't need this overload:

```
bool thing<N>::operator == (const char *) const
```

So I don't care if a solution breaks that flavor of `==`.

I did search through other posts here; there were a number with misleadingly similar titles that ended up being unrelated. It looks like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392600/binary-operator-overloading-implicit-type-conversion) had a *related* problem (undesired implicit conversions) but it's still not applicable.

---

For completeness, here is a slightly less minimal but more representative example of what I'm actually doing, where the intent is to allow `==` to work for `thing<T,N>` and `thing<R,N>`, that is, the `N`'s must be the same but the first template parameter can differ. I'm including this in case it affects a possible solution, since this is what I really need correct behavior for:

```
template <typename T, int N> struct thing {
  operator const char * () const { return nullptr; }
  template <typename R> bool operator == (const thing<R,N> &) const { return false; }
};

int main () {
  thing<int,0> i0;
  thing<float,0> f0;
  thing<int,1> i1;
  i0 == f0;
  f0 == i0;
  i0 == i1; // should fail to compile
  f0 == i1; // should fail to compile
  i1 == i0; // should fail to compile
  i1 == f0; // should fail to compile
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just provide a `delete`d version of the operator for the case where it shouldn't work, e.g.:

```
template <int N> struct thing {
  operator const void * () const { return nullptr; }
  bool operator == (const thing<N> &) const { return false; }
  template <int X>
  bool operator == (const thing<X> &) const = delete;
};

int main () {
  thing<0> a;
  thing<1> b;
  a == a; // This compiles
  a == b; // Doesn't compile
}
```

With C++20 the logic conveniently also extends to `operator!=`. With pre-C++20 compiler you should probably add corresponding overloads for `operator!=`, too.

Comment: Hey, good idea. I don't have a chance to try it right now so I can't test this but: in C++17 can the `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, and `-` binary operators also be deleted like this?

Comment: @JasonC: sure. It shouldn't be necessary, though, as none of these operators is defined for `void*` or `void const*`. Of course, if you convert to a different pointer type you may need to deal with them, too. ... with C++20 you can just use `operator<[=>` while for pre-C++20 you'll need t o deal with the whole set of operators.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make sure this all works when I get a chance (I'm sure it does, I just like to see it with my own eyes). Also thanks for the reminder about `void *` math. I should probably change it to `char *` or something in my example when I get home just to keep things representative. In my real code it's a different pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

If you mark the `operator const char *` as `explicit`, then your code will not compile.

`explicit` requires C++11, but you're already using `nullptr`, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Yeah; but I'd like to keep the conversion operator implicit. I mentioned that but it might have been buried in the length of the post. :)

Comment: Sorry I missed that.

Comment: In that case, @Dietmar's answer seems like the right way to go